# How to add a space before Link in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

How can I add a space before link? Without CSS of course

```
Please check if you agree with our 
<Link href="/[slug]" as="/privacy-policy/">
    <a>Privacy policy</a>
</Link>
```

I also have a space after "... our " but the outcome is still this:

```
Please check if you agree with ourPrivacy policy
```

Comment: Try putting a space in double quotes in curly braces before the `<a>` as in `{" "}<a>Privacy policy</a>`

Comment: `<a> Privacy policy</a>` is not working?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I get error "React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child." and I can't have a span either between because there won't be a link then.

Comment: @Nico Then it shows the space but on a:hover that space also has text-decoration: underline which still kinda sucks

Comment: if you surround what I suggested with a `<div>` it should work: `<div>{" "}<a>Privacy policy</a></div>` so that it satisfies having only one element inside. If that doesn't work, could you edit your question to have your entire `render()` function?

Comment: You might also try the `{" "}` before the `<Link>` tag as in `Please check if you agree with our {" "}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a space like this:

```
Please check if you agree with our 
{" "}
<Link href="/[slug]" as="/privacy-policy/">
    <a>Privacy policy</a>
</Link>
```

By placing the space in double quotes and surrounding by curly braces you tell React to interpret the expression inside the braces, which forces it to include the space as a literal string.

Comment: But these {" "} are converted to <!-- --> in the code source, it is better to concat previous string with space